# What event is Magento using for sending out order confirmation mails

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I am having some problems with a module i wrote. I have created observer that upload XML and send notification for admin.

I have testet with 2 events: `<sales_order_place_after>` and `<sales_order_save_after>`.

The problem is that i offer 2 types of payment option (bank transfer and creditcard). One change state immediately to `[New]` (banktransfer) and other is payment by credit card which goes to state `[Processing]` before payment is captured and then after payment has been captured `[New]`.

This gives me problem as because i only want to upload XML once for every order and `<sales_order_save_after>` trigger event for every order update and `<sales_order_place_after>` only gets triggered once and and not when payment have been captured.

I think solution would be to use same event as Magento use to send out order confirmation mail. Which event is that?

This is my observer that does not work correct.

`public function salesOrderSaveAfter($observer)
    {
    ....
    if ($orderStatus == 'pending' || $orderStatus == 'bank_transfer' ) {`

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Order confirmation emails are not triggered from an event. They are triggered from the `saveOrder()` method within class `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage`.

You should see some code like;

```
/**
 * a flag to set that there will be redirect to third party after confirmation
 * eg: paypal standard ipn
 */
$redirectUrl = $this->getQuote()->getPayment()->getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl();
/**
 * we only want to send to customer about new order when there is no redirect to third party
 */
if (!$redirectUrl && $order->getCanSendNewEmailFlag()) {
    try {
        $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
    }
}
```

This basically sends the confirmation email as soon as the order is placed unless the payment method has a redirect URL (i.e. Third party payment pages like PayPal standard).

If you do not want the email to be sent for a particular payment method you could override the function above and make it check the payment type;

```
if (!$redirectUrl && $order->getPayment()->getMethod() != 'your_payment_method' && $order->getCanSendNewEmailFlag()) {
    try {
        $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
    }
}
```

To trigger the sending of a confirmation email from your observer, simply load the order object and call `$order->sendNewOrderEmail();`.